# C# does not open the sqlite3 file

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've created a SQLite3 Database by Datagrid and dragged and dropped it into the solution folder. It does not connect and it shows the following error. please, one very simple solution, I am new in OOP. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

thanks for your help.

Comment: Check that file is present by this path for  your program. Cause when you start your program it usually starts in different folder, then the root folder of your project. Also please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: hey many thanks for your reply! the file (Dokan.sqlite3) is the solution folder, as you see in the picture. but if you could be more specific with your explanation, it would really great.

Comment: Your code is executed from other path(when you run your code via IDE), not from the root of your solution. So `"./Database/Dokan.sqlite3` will mean something like `"%solution_dir%/bin/debug/Database/Dokan.sqlite3"`  See Tam's answer.

Comment: thanks, I am working on his answer. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your "./Database/Dokan.sqlite3" file was not copied to your binary output folder, therefore when your code executed, it couldn't find any db called "./Database/Dokan.sqlite3".

Example: If your binary output folder is in c:\blahblah\bin\Debug, then you need to copy your "./Database/Dokan.sqlite3" file from your project into that directory so that "c:\blahblah\bin\Debug\Database\Dokan.sqlite3" exists.  Then when your CollectionTest.exe runs from c:\blahblah\bin\Debug, it will find the db file.

Comment: I've marked it as answer, if I did it correctly. now I am trying to print the datas correctly. I hope, I can write clear codes.

Comment: You're doing fine, Johny.  Remember, "a smooth sea never made a skilled sailor"! :)

Comment: thanks, I found it but I need a lot more practice to become profi like you :)))), have a wonderful rest day!